# Makefile: rule that is always executed only if other rule(s) are executed

Tags: makefile

I have this:

```
.PHONY: all shared_setup
all: foo bar

shared_setup:
    # do some stuff that always needs to be done if 'foo' or 'bar' run
    # but shouldn't be done if neither 'foo' nor 'bar' run

foo: shared_setup some_other_foo_prerequisite
    # do something that depends on shared_setup
    touch foo

bar: shared_setup some_other_bar_prerequisite
    # do something else that depends on shared_setup
    touch bar
```

When I run `make all`, I would like `shared_setup` to always be executed if `foo` or `bar` are executed, but not cause `foo` or `bar` to be considered out of date. Note as well, that `shared_setupd` shouldn't run if neither `foo` nor `bar` run.

Answer (score 1):

You could make `shared_setup` an *[order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)* (as opposed to a *normal prerequisite*) of both `foo` and `bar` (note the `|` symbol):

```
shared_setup:
    # do some stuff that always needs to be done if 'foo' or 'bar' run
    # but shouldn't be done if neither 'foo' nor 'bar' run

foo: some_other_foo_prerequisite | shared_setup
    # do something that depends on shared_setup
    touch foo

bar: some_other_bar_prerequisite | shared_setup
    # do something else that depends on shared_setup
    touch bar
```

This way, executing the rule `shared_setup` will cause neither `foo` nor `bar` to be outdated.

---

As a workaround  to "prevent" `shared_setup` from being executed every time, you could create the (non-`private`) *[target-specific variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html)* `must-run-shared-setup`. Let's consider it for the `foo` target:

```
foo: must-run-shared-setup := $(filter $|, $?)
foo: some_other_foo_prerequisite | shared_setup
    ....
```

The automatic variable `$?` contains the names of all the prerequisites (whether *normal* or *order-only*) that are newer than the target `foo`, and `$|` contains the names of all `foo`'s order-only prerequisites (i.e.: only, and always `shared_setup` for `foo`).

Since we are setting `must-run-shared-setup` to the result of filtering the contents of `$|` from `$?`, the `must-run-shared-setup` variable will be non-empty if `foo` must be updated, and empty otherwise.

This way, inside `shared_setup`'s recipe can be conditionally decided whether to do something or not, based on the content of this variable `must-run-shared-setup` (i.e.: actually whether it is empty or not).

You can proceed analogously for the `bar` target.

#### Simpler solution

This solution implies changing your design, but it seems much simpler to me. It consists of using an empty file, `shared_target`, as a simple timestamp, so that `make` can determine whether it should run it or not.

You could remove `shared_setup` from the list of the phony targets. Then, add it as an order-only prerequisite to both `foo` and `bar`. `shared_setup` should have all other prerequisites of both `foo` and `bar` and its recipe should create it as an empty file.

```
.PHONY: all
all: foo bar

shared_setup: some_other_foo_prerequisite some_other_bar_prerequisite
    # do some stuff that always needs to be done if 'foo' or 'bar' run
    # but shouldn't be done if neither 'foo' nor 'bar' run
    touch shared_setup 

foo: some_other_foo_prerequisite | shared_setup
    # do something that depends on shared_setup
    touch foo

bar: some_other_bar_prerequisite | shared_setup
    # do something else that depends on shared_setup
    touch bar
```

If either `foo` or `bar` must be updated because any of their prerequisites changed, so must `shared_setup`. If neither `foo` nor `bar` need to be updated, `shared_setup` doesn't need to be updated either, because the target `shared_setup` already exists and their prerequisites aren't newer.

Comment: Ah yes, I initially tried this but the problem here is that `shared_setup` is now always executed, even if neither `foo` or `bar` are

Comment: This is may be because `shared_setup` is the first target that appears in the makefile, you can try putting it at the end. How are you invoking `make`?

Comment: Sure, I updated my question to give a better example of what I want

Comment: @水飲み鳥 you listed shared_setup as both an order-only and non-order-only dependency of both foo and bar.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Corrected. Many Thanks :-)

Comment: Ah, that looks super promising, will test and mask as the answer if it works!

Comment: I've purposed a new much simpler solution.